# Under JDK 21, Maven compilation results in an error

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, java-21, openjdk-21

When I execute `mvn install -DskipTests` Maven gives me an error related to virtual threads

```html
[ERROR] /E:/mycode/javaproject/rms/rms-parse/src/main/java/com/example/config/AsyncConfig.java:[19,49] 鎵句笉鍒扮鍙
[ERROR]   绗﹀彿:   鏂规硶 newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()
[ERROR]   浣嶇疆: 绫?java.util.concurrent.Executorss
[ERROR] /E:/mycode/javaproject/rms/rms-parse/src/main/java/com/example/config/AsyncConfig.java:[25,50] 鎵句笉鍒扮鍙
[ERROR]   绗﹀彿:   鏂规硶 newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()
[ERROR]   浣嶇疆: 绫?java.util.concurrent.Executorss
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :rms-parse
```

Here is my main tools version:
Maven version: 3.9.5
JDK: 21
Project Stucture:

```
rms
  - rms-common
  - rms-parse
  - rms-admin
  - <some other sub-module>
  - pom.xml
```

rms's  pom.xml is(I have already omitted the configuration related to dependencies.):

```xml
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>rms</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>rms-parse</module>
    <module>rms-mapper</module>
    <module>rms-service</module>
    <module>rms-common</module>
    <module>rms-admin</module>
    <module>rms-model</module>
  </modules>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>


  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.github.shalousun</groupId>
          <artifactId>smart-doc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.7.7</version>
          <configuration>
            <!--指定生成文档的使用的配置文件-->
            <configFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/smart-doc.json</configFile>
            <!--指定项目名称-->
            <projectName>rms</projectName>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>compile</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>html</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.11.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>21</source>
            <target>21</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

The following is the code I'm using virtual threads in my project, and it's not compiling correctly.

```java
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class AsyncConfig {

    @Bean
    public AsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor() {
        return new TaskExecutorAdapter(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    public TomcatProtocolHandlerCustomizer<?> protocolHandlerVirtualThreadExecutorCustomizer() {
        return protocolHandler -> {
            protocolHandler.setExecutor(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor());
        };

    }
}
```

The following is the settings of maven about jdk setting, This file exists in two locations, one in ~/.m2, and the other in the conf directory of the Maven installation. I've configured both locations with the same settings.

```xml
  <profiles>
    <profile>    
      <id>jdk-21</id>    
      <activation>    
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>    
        <jdk>21</jdk>    
      </activation>    
      <properties>    
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>    
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>    
        <maven.compiler.compilerVersion>21</maven.compiler.compilerVersion>    
      </properties>    
  </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

I expect Maven to compile my project successfully.

Comment: Can you show the output of `mvn help:effective-pom`?

Comment: The console is outputting a lot of information. What specific information would you like me to filter?

Comment: I've recorded this information in a file. You can download and review it ; link is http://alist.duckflew.cn/d/%E5%8F%88%E6%8B%8D%E4%BA%91%E6%96%87%E4%BB%B6%E6%A1%B6/fullpom.txt

Comment: Can you try setting `<java.version>21</java.version>` in your `<properties>`?

Comment: when I set this property, it works, thx!

Comment: The profiles you have configured and the source/target configurations please remove them.. only use as suggested `java.version` (based on Spring Boot)...

Comment: Does this mean I don't need to specify configurations like <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source> in my Maven configuration file and only need <java.version>21</java.version> in the project's pom.xml?

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:
Add this to your pom file

```
<properties>
  <java.version>21</java.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: It'work for me, But have you noticed that the console output above is showing garbled characters? Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: This way it works only when you're using Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the only change in `pom.xml` to denote I want to use Java 21 was adding following properties:

```
    <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
```

After refreshing project in IntelliJ (in Maven tab), the IDE correctly recognized language features from Java 21.